# How to use reCaptcha v2 in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, recaptcha

I've tried so many times to add reCaptcha to my Vue 3 project. If anybody knows how to add reCaptcha to vue 3, please help me.

I tried to install the vue-reCaptcha npm package, but it didn't work. I wanted to add 'I'm not a robot' checkbox.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps to use reCAPTCHA in vue3 application.

1. Collect API key — You can sign up here (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro)
2. In your terminal, run the following command:

   ```
   Using Yarn: "yarn add vue-recaptcha"
   Using NPM: "npm i vue-recaptcha"
   ```

There's the code snippet you can follow.

```html
<template>
  <VueRecaptcha
    :sitekey="siteKey"
    :load-recaptcha-script="true"
    @verify="handleSuccess"
    @error="handleError"
  ></VueRecaptcha>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { VueRecaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ReCaptcha',
  components: {
    VueRecaptcha
  },
  setup() {
    const siteKey = computed(() => {
      return 'yourSiteAPIKey';
    });

    const handleError = () => {
      // Do some validation
    };

    const handleSuccess = (response: string) => {
     // Do some validation
    };

    return {
      handleSuccess,
      handleError,
      siteKey,
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

[image]

Head over to the docs to learn more about the props and methods you have available: https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha#readme

Comment: Got error. "Module '"vue-recaptcha"' has no exported member 'VueRecaptcha'. Did you mean to use 'import VueRecaptcha from "vue-recaptcha"' instead?"

Comment: @AbhinandK can you share your "devDependencies" section from package.json please ??

Comment: },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^3.0.0-alpha.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "typescript": "~5.0.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.9",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.6.5"
  }

Comment: @AbhinandK so what I found , 
There is a typo in the npm documentation we must read useReCaptcha and it has been written useRecaptcha. Change it and it may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your replies from the first answer below, it looks like you're using the vue-recaptcha 3.0.0-alpha. You should be using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha/v/2.0.3 this version as it's probably the most stable.

Although, the documentation for this version states that you need to wrap your submit button with the vue-recaptcha.

```js
            <VueRecaptcha
              class="full-width"
              :sitekey="siteKey"
              :load-recaptcha-script="true"
              @verify="handleSuccess"
              @error="handleError"
            >
              <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
            </VueRecaptcha>
```

which is not the checkbox that you're probably going for but this one should work.